# Convert datetime string to a different datetime string in PowerShell v2

Tags: datetime, powershell-2.0

I have the following string which is pulled from an entry in a log file.

```
$d = "19/09/2014 22:41:27"
```

However, I need to convert it so that it is

```
2014-09-19 22:41:27
```

so that I can export it with other sections of the logfile into a MySQL database.

But I can't for the life of me find a way to do this. I was expecting to find something like set-dateFormat, which would simply re-map the components of the string, but it doesn't seem to exist.

I have tried various variations of the following:

```
$a = "19/09/2014 22:41:27"
$d = [datetime]::ParseExact($a, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", $null)
$e = "{0:yyyymmddhhmmss}" -f [datetime]$d
```

But everything returns the error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

What is the best way to get the format I need please?

Comment: The error about "String is not recognized as a valid DateTime" is due to your ParseExact date format. You have 24 hour time listed in string $a, but you are attempting to read it as 12hour time by using lower case "hh:". If you use "HH:" instead it converts fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick play around, with the help of a few other blogs provided the following, very similar to your own. There's probably a way to make it a little more streamlined, but it will create the datetime object you need. Manipulating the output after that should be straightforward.

```
$theDTString = "19/09/2014 22:41:27".toString()
$theDateTimeObject = ([datetime]::ParseExact($theDTString,"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss",$null))

$theDateTimeObject.year.toString() + "-" + $theDateTimeObject.month.toString() +"-"+ 
$theDateTimeObject.day.toString() + " " + $theDateTimeObject.Hour.toString() + ":" +$theDateTimeObject.Minute.toString() + ":" + $theDateTimeObject.Second.toString()
```

Comment: Cheers, that was (almost) perfect. The only problem was that it missed the leading 0 on the month, so it had 9 instead of 09. I got round this by creating each section (day,month etc.) first, then checking the length (-lt 2), and adding the 0, before constructing the final date.

Answer (score 1):

The identical answer to your original input is this:

```
$a = "19/09/2014 22:41:27"
$d = [datetime]::ParseExact($a, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", $null)
$e = "{0:yyyymmddhhmmss}" -f [datetime]$d
```

It was having an error trying to convert hour 22 as a 12 Hour format.